# Pointer to a Vector of Class - I can't reach the members of the Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, heap-memory

I try to create a vector with a pointer (so that everything is stored in/on the heap). I then want to fill the vector with an array of a class. I am thinking about accessing the class by `class[i].member`... Sadly, it does not work. 
If I try this without a vector it works, like in:

```
tClass *MyClass = new tClass[5]
```

I am trying this without a specific purpose and only to understand C++ better. Can anyone have a look where I am wrong? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

class tClass
{
private:
   int x = 0;
public:
   int y = 0;
tClass(){cout << "New" << endl;};
~tClass(){}; //do I need to make a delete here?

int main ()
{
   vector<tClass> *MyClass[5];
   MyClass = new vector<tClass>[5];
   cout << MyClass[3].y << endl;
   delete[] MyClass;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want an array of vectors, or an array of pointers to vector? The declaration `vector<tClass> *MyClass[5];` produces the latter, but `new vector<tClass>[5]` creates the former. Either way, `MyClass[3]` would be either a `vector` or a pointer to `vector`, neither of which has a member named `y`.

Comment: If you want a vector containing 5 instances of `tClass` (as `new tClass[5]` would appear to suggest), then make it `vector<tClass> MyClass(5);` You are making it way too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for that analysis of my 'code'. I fixed the issue now with your advice on the Syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others have suggested if you want just a vector of tClass you would do the following

```
vector<tClass> vectorName (5);
```

and access it like so

```
vectorName[3].y;
```

however if you wanted a vector of tClass pointers you would initialise and acess it like this

```
vector<tClass*> vectorName(5);
vectorName[3]->y;
```

edit

this might help you a bit more, this is your code, with comment to help you understand what is going wrong

```
class tClass
```

{
private:
    int x = 0;
public:
    int y = 0;
    tClass(){ cout << "New" << endl; };
    ~tClass(){}; //do I need to make a delete here?         //no you dont need to make a delete here as this class contains no "news"

```
int main()
{
    vector<tClass> *MyClass[5]; //use () to give a vector an initial size, [] is only to access a member
                                //also to have a vector holding pointers, the asterisk needs to be after tClass not before the vector name
    MyClass = new vector<tClass>[5];        
    cout << MyClass[3].y << endl;       //discused above
    delete[] MyClass;                   //only needed if a new is used, however you dont need one here, as it will just go out of scope
}
```

here is you code, but fixed to compile and run with the use of pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class tClass
{
private:
    int x = 0;
public:
    int y = 0;
    tClass(){ cout << "New" << endl; };
};

int main()
{
    vector<tClass*> MyClass(5);
    cout << MyClass[3]->y << endl;
}
```

note though that this will give an error as the vector of class pointers are not pointing to any class

Comment: Dear Igor and Crimson, Thanks for your help!  May I ask your for a little more? The above 'code' came to me when I saw the following code in my tutorial books:

`int main () {
vector<int> *var; var = new int (5); std::cout << var[1]; 
}`

I am now trying to understand why it does not work when I replace int by a class. 

Apart from that, may I ask you to give me an example of how 
`vector<tClass*> vectorName(5);
vectorName[3]->y;`
 works with a "new" or is that not possible (sorry if my questions are noobish, but i'd feel a lot better if I understand this)

Comment: I'm happy to help, when accessing a class member from a pointer, instead of using a dot, you need to use pointer notation, the "->" or you can even do the following if you wish "(*vectorName[3]).y" if you prefer using the . notation. in this particular case you don't need to use new. Generally you only want to use new when you want to delete a pointer at a known place, i.e. not when it goes out of scope. simply declaring something a pointer with the asterisk will do

Comment: Dear Crimson, Thanks again! I reviewed my syntax and your comments and I think the following now does the trick:
`vector<t_class*> MyClass2(5);
 for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  MyClass2[i] = new t_class;
 MyClass2[2]->y = 4; delete[]MyClass2`. Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help, added a but more to my solution as well

Comment: `vector<int> *var; var = new int (5);` If that's really what your book says, then demand your money back and get a better book. This piece of code makes no sense whatsoever, and has no chance of compiling. It is perhaps more likely that you are badly mis-quoting the code from the book.